# neo4j core java api sample projects

Tags: neo4j, spring-data-neo4j, java

We need to write some restful services to access / creates data on Neo4j. I have found many examples in Traverser Framework but I would like to explore Java CORE API as it is mentioned that the performance of Java Core API is far better than Traverser as per  [this link](http://java.dzone.com/articles/get-full-neo4j-power-using)

Is it true? that Java CORE API is better than Traverser? Can someone guide me with useful tutorials of Java Core API for Neo4j?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider asking a different question here.

I don't dispute the performance finding that the traverser API is slower than the core API, but keep in mind that it's only for the kinds of things they were trying to do in that test.

Which API you should use depends on what you're trying to do.  Without providing information on that, we can't suggest which will be the fastest for you.

Here are your tradeoff options:  if you use the core API, then you can perform exactly the low-level operations on the graph that you want.  On the flipside, you have to do all of the work.  If the operations you're trying to do are complex, far reaching, or order-sensitive, you'll find yourself writing so much code that you'll re-implement a buggy version of the Traversal API on you own.   Avoid this at all costs!  The performance of the Traversal API is almost certainly better than what you'll write on your own.

On the other hand, if the operations you're performing are very simple (look up a node, grab its immediate neighbors by some edge type, then return them) then the core API is an excellent choice.  In this (very simple) case, you don't need all the bells and whistles that Traversal gives you.

Bigger than just your question though:  in general it's good to avoid "premature optimization".  If a library or framework gives you a technique like the Traversal API, as a starting point it's a good bet to learn that abstraction and use it, because the developers gave it to you to make your life easier, not to make your code slower.  If it turns out to be more than you need, or performance is really lagging -- then consider using the core API.

In the long run, if you're going to write RESTful services over top of Neo4J, you'll probably end up knowing both APIs.   Bottom line - it's not a matter of choosing *which one* you should use, it's a matter of understanding their differences and which situations play to their strengths.